# How do I have the main thread wait for other threads when using the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a main thread that starts a few worker threads through a class that implements the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx).  Unfortunately, as soon as the main thread is done setting up the worker threads, it exits.

I want the main thread to wait indefinitely until the `anEventHandler` method is called, then process that method.  The `asyncevents` listen for events indefinitely until canceled, so they might call the `anEventHandler` method multiple times before completing.

NOTE: There is no related GUI, I'm just using this pattern.

```
   public static void Main(String[] args) {
        AsyncEventClass asyncevent = new AsyncEventClass();

        // setup event handling
        asyncevent.Events += new EventsHandler(anEventHandler);

        // start event monitoring threads
        asyncevent.monitorAsync(1);
        asyncevent.monitorAsync(2);
        asyncevent.monitorAsync(3);

        System.Console.WriteLine("The main thread now ends. :(");
    }
```

All the examples online use `System.Console.ReadLine()`, but that seems like a terrible idea in production code.

Comment: I guess I could expose the IAsyncResult that the AsyncEventClass creates by implementing the Event-based Async Pattern, and wait on that.  Is there a better way?  I'd like to avoid exposing that (for coupling reasons) if possible.

Comment: Do you have to use this pattern? If you're able to use tasks instead, it makes life simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting all of the `IAsyncResutl` objects returned by calling `WorkerEventHandler.BeginInvoke` into a list, and then exposing that list to the `Main` method.  There, I setup all the asyncevents I need to listen for, then use `WaitHandle.WaitAll` to wait for the events to complete.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) which you wait for in the main method, and set in the event handler.

If you want to wait for a specific amount of times that the eventhandler is called, I guess you can keep a counter, and set the auto-reset-event only when you reach a certain threshold.